# concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor doens't print error/

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am using "concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor" to run my function in parallel on CPU:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
futures = [executor.submit(operation, bag_candidate_idx) for bag_candidate_idx in range(total)]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

The problem is that it doesn't kill the whole run if it faces a run time error or doesn't print the error in the log file.

I wonder how I can print run-time errors in each separate thread while using concurrent.futures?